# Bootstrap confusion about grids

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to convert my non responsive site to responsive using bootstrap. I am starting with the top banner. It is 1000px * 400 px. It has a login link on top right. Below that on the left there is a site title saying(my website title: slogan). And below that on the right there is search. I am able to implement it but confused about how to do it. My site is fixed container 1024px.

[image]

```
  <div class="container" style="max-width:1024;width:98%" >
      <div id="banner-holder" class="row"> 
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 clearfix">
                   <p style="float:right;">Login links</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12 clearfix">
                  <p style="float:left;">Site banner title</p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 clearfix">
                   <p style="float:right;">search box</p>
                </div>
            </div> 
         </div>     
      </div><!-- row holding bannder ends here-->  
  </div><!--container ends here-->
```

I have few doubts? Like is it okay to give three rows directly inside one row or should 
I give an intermediate col-md-12 like given above?

Is this code the right way to do what I am trying to achieve  or is there a better way and is this correct from
bootstrap rules.. I am new to bootstrap and I feel guilty I am not abiding by rules.

Comment: There's nothing incorrect about your markup, however you don't need the extra `row` and `col-md-12` surrounding each of your elements.

Comment: @technophobia is it necessary for col-md-* inside every row to add up to 12 and could you add an answer after cleaning unnecessary stuff from mine if possible

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in the comment, your nesting is correct but may be extraneous.

**Simplified Markup**

```
<div class="container" style="max-width:1024;width:98%" >
    <div id="banner-holder" class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <p class="pull-right">Login links</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <p class="pull-left">Site banner title</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <p class="pull-right">search box</p>
            </div> 
        </div>     
    </div><!-- row holding bannder ends here-->  
</div><!--container ends here-->
```

To answer your question in the above comment:

> is it necessary for col-md-* inside every row to add up to 12?

That is almost correct, the sum of `col-md-*` should **not exceed** 12 within a row in order to maintain the desired column layout on medium device resolution.

**Note about offsets:**
if you're using `col-*-offset-*`, make sure the sums of the `col`s *and* `offset`s does not exceed 12 within a row.